# Qt ensureVisible() not working in QScrollArea

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qscrollarea

I have 2 column. One of the columns is filled with lots of QWidgets.
When I drop a widget in a column I call this method:

```
void MainWindow::scrollToItem(Product_View *item) {
    QPoint point = item->mapToParent(QPoint());
    ui->scrollArea->ensureVisible(point.x(), point.y());
}
```

When I am at the bottom of the first column and I drag a widget in the next one. The scrollarea scrolls properly to the bottom so that I can see where I dropped it.

But when I drop the widget back in the first column, it scrolls but not entirely to the bottom. Its of about 150px (EDIT: 150px is not true. I only see about 5px of the Widget)

Can anybody help me?

EDIT:

maybe good to know my layout.

I have a mainwindow with a `QScrollArea`.
The scrollArea has a `QWidget` called `scrollAreaWidgetContents` and it has a QHBoxLayout.
The widget has 5 columns. And these have QVBoxLayout for my drag and drop widgets.

JEEZ ANOTHER EDIT:

I notice it only goes wrong with the last item.

I JUST KEEP ON EDITING

It is now clear to me that the scrollbar just isn't going all the way down.

```
QScrollBar *bar = ui->scrollArea->verticalScrollBar();
bar->setValue(bar->maximum());
```

This code also shows the same behaviour. What should I do with this thread? And should I create a new one?

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an older post I encountered the same problem and it gave me a lot of trouble finding a solution.

My problem:
Had to add a new line to a widget and then make sure the scroll bar scrolls down to it in order for people to view it. OP describes the issue well in his answer.

The things I tried are:
**1.** (**Best way**) To call processEvents() on the app object. I tried it after I saw [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/30632-QScrollArea-Scroll-to-widget-problem) post and ratzian's answer.

**2.** Implement your custom ScrollArea,that extends `QScrollArea` and override the resize handler to be able to call ensureWidgetVisible on the added widget. Of course it somehow needs to know about that widget object.

**3.** Add a `QTimer` and start the timer upon adding a new widget. The method that the timer calls will need to call ensureWidgetVisible() on the new widget object and afterwards stop the timer.

I am aware that 3 is a bit hacky since it doesnt know when the resize event took place and so the timer will need to be set to a suboptimal value. (e.g resize is called in 33 ms and you set timer to 500 ms, you get the idea).

I hope this manages to help people who struggle with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The [ensureVisible](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#ensureVisible) function only takes a point, so using it will only guarantee that one corner of your widget is visible (the top left, I believe?).  Try using [ensureWidgetVisible](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#ensureWidgetVisible) instead - this should make sure the entire widget makes it on-screen.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You're right about using `ensureWidgetVisible`. But I did that before with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. Not the solution.

If I drag the widget back to the first column, my code calls `ensureWidgetVisible`.
After that, my scrollArea resizes because of the new item. So thats why my widget isn't entirely visible.